# Picking elements from array

Tags: python

I have two arrays in python:

```
import numpy as np

p=np.array([0.3,0.2,0.1,0.4])

k=np.array([0,1,2,1])

want=np.array([0.3,0.2,0.1,0.2])
```

I want to return a new array, want, with the same length as k, where the elements are picked from the p array. The elements of k tells which index to pick from p, i.e. first it should pick index 0 from p, then index 1, then index 2 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
import numpy as np

p=np.array([0.3,0.2,0.1,0.4])

k=np.array([0,1,2,1])

want=p[k]
```

Comment: is this helped you ?

Comment: I didn't know this form, I like it!

Answer (score 1):

Use `list comprehension`

```
want = np.array([p[i] for i in k])
```

or simply pass the indexes *k* to *p*

```
want = p[k]
```

Comment: in the second case you don't neet to force np.array() you just use want=p[k] as responded above

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution:

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4])
k = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1])
want = np.array([0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2])

want = np.array([p[i] for i in k])

print('Output:', want)

# Output: [0.3 0.2 0.1 0.2]
```